# Does a L2S bindingsource not add the 'addnew' object to the datacontext?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql, datacontext, bindingsource

I'm using a Linq to Sql bindingsource on a winform tied to a datagridview. After I do an AddNew and SubmitChanges it does not seem to save to the database.

```
var myObject = (myObject)myBindingSource.AddNew();
myObject.ID=123;
myObject.prop="test";
myDataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

then when I check the database the object is not there. 
Doesn't the datacontext get told by the bindingsource that I want to insert an object?

If I change the code to:

```
var myObject = (myObject)myBindingSource.AddNew();
myObject.ID=123;
myObject.prop="test";
myDataContext.MyObjects.InsertOnSubmit(myObject);
myDataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

it works. It seems double work since I ws expecting the bindingsource to take care of it.

Comment: mmm.... I actually just ran into a situation where it's better that the bindingsource DOES NOT insertonsubmit the object right away.  When the users are setting more details in a drilldown form and decide that they don't want the object anyway, you can just cancel and you're not stuck with an object in the datacontext!

Comment: it's getting stranger - I just found some code that used to work WITHOUT the 'InsertOnSubmit'. Now it doesn't anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This question is kind of old - I actually forget I had asked it myself! 
So it's weird to come across it in a search for the same issue more than a year later.
I did find a solution though.

At first, I used something like this (which doesn't work):

`myBindingSource.DataSource = myLinqToSqlDataContext.SomeTable.ToList();`

When I used:

```
myBindingSOurce.DataSource = myLinqToSqlDataContext.SomeTable.Take(20);
```

the bindingsource will update the underlying database for inserts and deletes without problems.

So I quess it's important to make sure the datasource is an IQueryable instead of a List.